# Why are there 0 users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

I was checking the reputation leagues this morning and noticed something odd.

[image]

As you can see, there are -229,498 users with 1+ Total Reputation. 229,498 is the sum of the rest of the numbers, which means that there seems to be no users on Stack Overflow.

[image]

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: how can we test this???? share link of query plz.

Comment: Definitely oscillation.

Comment: I would say overflow!!

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed it is on the right side of the page [here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2013-04-01/937623#937623). It is not a query I wrote.

Comment: For those that wanted the link, [clicky click](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow). Very odd. It seems we've been deleted from the internet.

Comment: Given that the list of sites ordered by users also shows SO at the bottom at the moment, I'm guessing we have a temporary glitch. http://stackexchange.com/sites#users. Time for some spinning http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/AYPpF/

Comment: I get -280k so it's dropping fast :-).

Comment: We are probably anti-users.  Don't approach real users, else we anihilate each other.

Comment: 0 answers as well, according to http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @Bart 0 total answers as well... looks like server cache glitch indeed. :)

Comment: 4.9m questions, 0 answers, yet a 100% answered rate. Suspicious indeed.

Comment: "5 million questions, not a single answer" Hey, that's a great motto for the site!

Comment: @Yannis at least with no answers, `Jon Skeet` is still king.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently seeing this, so it seems whatever this problem was has gone away.

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Yes, all seems to be right in the world.

Comment: I miss Nick and his lengthy explanations about failing servers and crashing buildings! :)